# How to reuse modal as a confirm dialog for delete actions from controllers in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having some controllers, both of them also have a delete function trigger by the `ng-click` and when delete function is called, i'll show a js confirm dialog to alert user about the object they're going to delete.

But now, i want to use the bootstrap instead of js confirm dialog for alert user, and all of delete function when called will use the same modal to alert, but the content of modal will be change by the delete function called. So can i make that with only 1 modal?

```
<div id="modal_alert_dialog" class="modal fade modalAlert" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">x</span>
                <h3 style="text-align:left;">Notice!</h3>
                <p class="text-left">Are you sure you want to delete {{object_name}}</p>// object_name variable is the name of object that user chosen to delete.
                <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="close btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn" ng-click="dynamicDeleteFunction">OK</button>//dynamicDeleteFunction is the fuction which user choose as a confirm "yes"
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('userController', function ($scope){
  $scope.deleteUser = function () {
    $scope.object_name = "user 'ABC'";
    //Maybe a function or something trigger the modal show up
    if (confirmed){
      //execute delete....
    }
  }
});
```

```
app.controller('productController', function ($scope){
  $scope.deleteProduct = function () {
    $scope.object_name = "product 'ABC-111'";
    //Maybe a function or something trigger the modal show up
    if (confirmed){
      //execute delete....
    }
  }
});
```

```
app.controller('categoryController', function ($scope){
    $scope.object_name = "category 'CatI'";
    //Maybe a function or something trigger the modal show up
    if (confirmed){
      //execute delete....
    }
});
```

Comment: you could create a controller for this modal and send your string var to it when changing route

Comment: so i'll need the connect between these controllers to modal controller?